# CollectionViewのセルごとに中身のレイアウトを変える

Tags: objective-c, uicollectionview

`CollectionView`のセルごとにセル内のレイアウトを変えたいと思っているのですがどうすればできるのでしょうか？例えば`CollectionView`で3ページ分のページング処理を実装したとして、各ページごとにボタンや画像を異なるレイアウトで配置したいとします。この場合はカスタムビューを使うのでしょうか？それとも`cellForItemAtIndexPath`内でコードで書いていくのでしょうか？
どなたか分かる方がいれば教えていただきたいです。すみませんが、よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

Storyboardを使用しているのであれば、
Storyboard上で数種類のレイアウトのUICollectionViewCellを作成して、
Identifierで名前をつけておきcellForItemAtIndexPathのcell生成時に指定することができます。

```
NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cellのIdentifier";
UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。Storyboard上でセルを作成すればよろしいのですね。後でその方法で実装してみたいと思います。